Is this Clairaut's type equation (?) solved correctly?
Tried to solve this
$$
y^2+x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=xy\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.
$$
with $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=p$ by dividing $x^2$,
$$
\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-\frac{y}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0\tag1.
$$
If it is solved in the fashion of Clairaut's equation, the solution can be simply
$$
\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2=p\left(\frac{y}{x}-1\right)\tag2.
$$
But the solution is found to be $ye^{-y/x}=C$
EDIT:
As pointed by @Moo, the coefficients are homogenous in $x$ and $y$ and in deed the substitution of $y=vx$ can solve it. For $y'=xv'+v$, (1) becomes
$$
v^2+(1-v)*(xv'+v)=0\implies(1-\frac{1}{v})\rm{d}v=\frac{\rm{d}x}{x}
$$
from there we integrate to have
$$
v-\ln v=\ln x-\ln C\implies\ln\frac{xv}{C}=v\implies xv=y=Ce^\frac{y}{x}
$$
as the provided solution.
But I was confused about the method by Art16 P21 in Forsyth's Differential Equation:



Regarding the equation type, it may not be correct to say Clairaut's form.

In what sense does this resemble a Clairaut equation $y=xy'+f(y')$?

I don't see what you mean by "in the fashion of Clairaut's equation, $y(x) = x y'(x) + f(y'(x))$ (indeed, Clairaut's equation has a $1$-parameter family of linear solutions, which is not the case for this equation). Rewriting the equation as
$$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 = p \left(\frac{y}{x} - 1\right)$$
is valid, but while it's an algebraic equation in $x, y, p$, it's still a differential equation in $y(x)$.
Hint To solve the equation (i.e., produce an algebraic equation for $y$), we can take further advantage of the homogeneity of the coefficients taht you've already observed: Let $v := \frac{y}{x}$ (in which case $p = x v' + v$), after which the equation becomes separable:
$$\frac{v}{v - 1} v' = \frac1x.$$

 Integrating gives $$v - \log |v| + B = \log x,$$ and rearranging (for $v > 0$) yields $$x v e^{-v} = C .$$ Now, change variable back to $y$. We can write (parts) of solutions using the Lambert $W$ function


Yes, I was a bit of confusion about the methods of solving Clairaut's equation which seems to me that if you can find the equation about parameter $p$ the job is done.
